# "no data found" shows in oracle recycle bin

Tags: oracle10g

[oracle 10g window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuSgI.png)

I have already deleted the table but it doesn't show in recycle bin .. and message is "no data found"

Comment: Did you *delete* from the table, or *drop* the table? And if you did drop it, did you include the `purge` keyword? (Also, it's not a good idea to do anything in the system schema, you should have your own user/schema and only work under that.)

Comment: I have own user . but i didn't use purge. I think purge is used when u doesn't want to  retrieve dropped table in future again.

Comment: Exactly, but if you had done `drop ... purge` then that would explain why the recycle bin is empty. So, did you create and drop the table as system, or as your own user? If you did that as your own user, why are you looking in system's recycle bin, instead of your own?